# Regular Expression PHP BUG or What?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

var_dump(preg_match('#((.*)*/)#i', 'a/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));
//return int 1

var_dump(preg_match('#((.*)*/)#i', 'a/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));
//return boolean false

?>
```

Whereas the regular expression is the same, and what changes is only the text that is being evaluated.

On the first line of code returns true, the faster and the second returns false, and slower ... coming to crash if placed in loop

There is an explanation for this, or is BUG
Trying other compliladores the result is the same

In Chrome console for example, this expression put the high processor clock

```
/((.*)*\/)/.test('a/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
```

In Flex, again... the same problem

I make this question because I had a code that some input parameters work, and others do not .. then simplified expression for the simplest point to demonstrate the error and got this case I'm showing.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php

Comment: The TL;DR is that you are hitting `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR` with that pattern and string.

Comment: There is a good chance you can just optimize your pattern, but without the specifics it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I can optimize, just wanted to understand what was happening that did not work.
I tested it and it really showed the problem that sent me the link
`code`
if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR)
{
 print 'Backtrack limit was exhausted!';
}
`code`

Comment: BACKTRACK_LIMIT would be what?

Comment: @Desenvolvedor `*` is greedy. It gobbles as much as possible at first and then has to backtrack and not gobble so much if it can't find a match. The way your regular expression is made means that this backtracking has to happen more times than the limit allows. See [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) about catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: thank you for @Phylogenesis tips, I will study this link